# Swift connection to Active Directory server

Tags: swift, active-directory, ldap, xcode6

I am building a Cocoa OS X app (10.10) in Xcode using Swift and I am trying to connect to an enterprise AD server in my institution for both authentication and directory lookups.

I am fairly confident that the code that I am using is correct but I am getting an error stating

> Session can't be opened because daemon refused the connection.

here is my connection code:

```
let options: [String:String] = [kODSessionProxyAddress: "ldap://address.com", kODSessionProxyUsername: "username", kODSessionProxyPassword: "password"]
var err:NSError?
var session = ODSession(options: options, error: &err)
println("ERROR: \(err)")
```

When I run this I get:

```
ERROR: Optional(Error Domain=com.apple.OpenDirectory Code=1003 "Unable to open proxy session" 
UserInfo=0x610000066280 {NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to open proxy session, 
NSLocalizedFailureReason=Session can't be opened because daemon refused the connection.})
```

I am not an AD administrator for the enterprise system so can not make alterations there so if, as I am suspecting, this is a restriction on the server side I guess there is not much I can do.

But if anyone can offer advice or a solution I would be greatful.

For a bit of extra info, from the computer I am coding on, I can successfully run ldapsearch commands from terminal so I know I have connectivity to the server. Also, my machine is not bound to the server so using `ODSession.defaultSession()` is out as far as I know?